# Localhost Mail() issues

Tags: php

I am trying to send mail via the `mail()` method, but I am doing it on my localhost, which does not appear to have a SMTP server running.

I think the code is fine, and the mail method itself is returning `true`, but could someone tell me if there is anything wrong with the use of the function before I put it onto my production server?

```
$mail('john@me.com', 'Title', 'John has send you a link to title','From: john@me.com X-Mailer: PHP/5.2.11');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your email headers need to be seperated by CRLFs.
From php.net:

> Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (`\r\n`)

so you would need to add in `"\r\n"` between header declarations.

Example from php.net ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php )

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```